# NSRegularExpression for a YouTube link

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I am trying to capture a YouTube link from a string of text using NSRegularExpression although not sure how to capture the entire link I can get it to match using this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http://youtube.*"
                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                  error:&error];
```

Example string:

```
"Hello please take a look at the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-UwOWB9Io4&feature=youtu.be  For tomorrow thanks."
```

Any thoughts on how this could be achieved?

Comment: edited for example URL

Comment: ObjC or Swift? Looks like Objective-C.

Comment: ObjC is the language thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes that the URL starts with "http" or "https" and that there are no spaces in the URL and a space immediatly following the URL, this seems reasonable.

```
NSString *searchString = @"Hello please take a look at the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-UwOWB9Io4&feature=youtu.be For tomorrow thanks.";

NSRange   searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length]);
NSString *pattern = @"(http[s]?://www.youtube.com\\S+)";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:searchString options:0 range: searchRange];
NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"matchRange: %@", NSStringFromRange(matchRange));
NSString *matchString = [searchString substringWithRange:matchRange];
NSLog(@"matchString: %@", matchString);
```

Output:

> matchRange: {43, 60}
>   matchString: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-UwOWB9Io4&feature=youtu.be

If you want the "www." to be optional you can use thei pattern (tip of the hat to @MikeAtNobel for the idea:

```
"(http[s]?://(?:www\\.)?youtube.com\\S+)"
```

ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: Why are there 2 backslashes in front of the `S` in your regular expression?

Comment: Because the "C" language requires it.

Comment: A warning is generated by the compiler: Unknown escape sequence '\.'

Comment: would it be possible to get the NSRange of the captured match within the string?

Comment: The range is already there and being used in the `NSLog()`, to get it individualy: `NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];`. I have added this to the answer.